# Reddit API: User clicks through to original article instead of Reddit link. Does this violate Same Origin Policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I have a feed-reader that displays a list of articles from the Reddit API.

http://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/WpqGap

When the user hovers on a picture, clicking on the text will take them to the original Reddit link.

Links are loaded by this line of code:

```
let link    = $('<a>').addClass('post').attr({target: '_blank', href: permalink}).appendTo(bar).text(posts[i].data.title);
```

1. Is it possible to retrieve the **original article link** from the Reddit API? i.e the user goes through to the original article, without stopping on Reddit? **If so, how?** Or will the user have to click through to the Subreddit?
2. Would linking to the original article violate Same Origin Policy?

> Security on the web depends on a variety of mechanisms, including an
>   underlying concept of trust known as the same-origin policy. This
>   essentially states that if content from one site (such as
>   https://mybank.example1.com) is granted permission to access resources
>   on a system, then any content from that site will share these
>   permissions, while content from another site
>   (https://othersite.example2.com) will have to be granted permissions
>   separately.[2]

Comment: 2. no it doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer.

Comment: sorry for the other i don't have an answare (anyway it don't violate because you have only a link reference, you are not requesting resources directly to the server, the apis resolve this problem)